# How to get the same size of picture and items on all devices?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to have the same size and scale of images and items on both devices. But they are different. Especially on Android the scale is really strange. I tried several things px and %. But that didn't work. At the moment its in %. When I run the app on my iPhone X it again different. So do you know how I can have the same size and scale on all the devices.

Here is the CSS Code

```
.hey{
   position: absolute; left: 76%; top: 21%;
}

#avatar{
  height: 25%; 
  width: 35%; 
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;

 position: absolute; left:35%; bottom: 70%;
}
```

[Left(IOS) Right(Android)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jr7m.png)

Answer (score 0):

try to use max-width and max-height properties to fix the image

```
#avatar{
  height: 25% !important; 
  width: 35% !important;
  max-width : 250px !important;
  max-height : 350px !important; 
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;

  position: absolute; left:35%; bottom: 70%;
```

}

Comment: with this code I'm having still the same problem. But thx for the answer